# Is the expectation of a single-root function, another single-root function?

Tags: convex-analysis, expectation, roots, random

Does $\mathbb{E}_a[f(x,a)]=0$ have a single root $x^*$ if $f(x,a)=0$ is a single-root function in $x$ for any $a$? 
Notice that $a$ is random with some given PDF.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $a$ be a random variable that takes the values $0$ and $1$ with equal probabilities and define $f(x,0)=x$ and $f(x,1)=x^2$. Both functions have the single root $x^*=0$. Then $\mathbb{E}[f(x,a)]=[x+x^2]/2$, which has two real roots, namely $x^*_1=0$ and $x^*_2=-1$.